# How to read this line of code

Tags: java, csv

I am using this

```
while ((nextLine = br.readNext()) != null) {
```

quite frequent but I don't really understand it.
It is part of the code where the csv file is uploaded.
Basically I would like to know, hot to read it.
Nextline is defined as: `String[] nextLine;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop part is easy:

```
while (____ != null) {
```

It'll keep looping while `____` is not equal to `null`. So let's look at what `____` is doing:

```
(nextLine = br.readNext())
```

That code's an assignemnt: It calls `br.readNext()` and assigns the result to `nextLine`. The key is that the *result* of an assignment is the value that was assigned.

So:

- If `br.readNext()` returns something that isn't `null`, it gets assigned to `nextLine` and the code goes into the body of the loop.
- If `br.readNext()` returns `null`, it gets assigned to `nextLine` and the loop terminates, because `null != null` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
while ((nextLine = br.readNext()) != null) {
```

takes advantage of the fact that an "assignment" is also an "expression" that has a value - the assigned value.

So the line, reading from inside the parentheses out, does the following:

1. Calls `readNext()` for the object `br`;
2. Assigns the result of the call to `nextLine`;
3. Tests the value assigned for `null`;
4. If it *is* `null`, it jumps past the body of the `while` loop, to 7.;
5. If it is *not* `null`, it executes the body of the `while` loop;
6. It then goes back to 1. again.
7. It continues the program.